# Error when using gem 'devise' for an already existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I just tried to add gem 'devise' and met some errors.

But before that I created a model User like this:

```
    class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
    def change
    create_table :users do |t|
        t.string :name
        t.string :email
        t.integer :role
        t.string :password_digest
        t.timestamps
    end
    end
    end
```

Then I ran command 'rails generate devise User' and it created a migrate 
add_devise_to_user:

```
    class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
    def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
    ## Database authenticatable

    t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
    t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
    ## Recoverable
    t.string   :reset_password_token
    t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at
    ## Rememberable
    t.datetime :remember_created_at
    ## Trackable
    t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
    t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
    t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
    t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

    ## Confirmable
    # t.string   :confirmation_token
    # t.datetime :confirmed_at
    # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
    # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

    ## Lockable
    # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if 
    lock strategy is :failed_attempts
    # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email 
    or :both
    # t.datetime :locked_at
    # Uncomment below if timestamps were not included in your 
    original model.
    t.timestamps null: false
    end

    # add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
    end

    def self.down
    # By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to 
    roll back a migration when your
    # model already existed. Please edit below which fields you 
    would like to remove in this migration.
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
    end
    end
```

Whenever I try to run rails db:migrate , the terminal show me these errors

```
    == 20190331081250 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
```

-- change_table(:users)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'email': ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'email': ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL

I have checked the questions and solutions that people have given, but none of them helped me solve this problem ( I'm new here )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block in `change_table` add columns to existed table `users`. In `change_table` you trying to add column `email`, but this column already exists in table `users`. This column was created in your first migration.

You should comment follow string in devise migration:

```rb
 t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
```

And add follow string in devise migration after `change_table` (NOT IN BLOCK) method:

```rb
change_column :users, :email, :string, null: false, default: ""
```

Comment: after doing what u said, i  see that the problem still there but with other attributes like  **encypted_password** , **sign_in_count** , etc...

Comment: @MinhTâmLương Look into you `db/schema.rb`. Do you see that columns for `users`?

Comment: okay, base on your idea, i actually deleted the block and changed every atrributes as the email sample you gave me, and I can migrate. So I think It's good to go now. Thanks !!!!!!!!

Comment: yeah , i have the columns for user

Comment: @MinhTâmLương it's mean that this colums already exists for your table and you try execute migration for creation columns second time. If you work with development environment and you don't need data in databse, I recommend drop db and rerun all migrations.